# Run Macro to generate code from parent class in Scala

Tags: scala, class, reflection, scala-macros

I have a macro that I use to generate some code to call methods dynamically. The macro is more complex than this, but for simplicity let's say it works something like this

```
def myMacro[T]: Seq[MethodName]
```

so than when called on

```
class Hello {
  def one(a: Int, b: UserId): String = a.toString + b.id

  def two(c: Option[Int]): String = ""

  def three(d: Seq[Int], f: Set[Int]): String = ""
}
println(myMacro[Hello]) // Seq("one", "two", "three")
```

I need this macro to generate code for an internal framework we use at Candu, but I need to be able to call it from the parent's class. So what I want to achieve is:

```
trait Superclass {
  def aFakeMethod: String = ""

  val methods = myMacro[Self] // FIXME! self is not defined here...
}

class Hello extends Superclass {
  def one(a: Int, b: UserId): String = a.toString + b.id

  def two(c: Option[Int]): String = ""

  def three(d: Seq[Int], f: Set[Int]): String = ""
}
val hi = new Hello
println(hi.methods) // Seq("one", "two", "three")
```

Because the high number of classes in the framework, modifying the api between `Hello` and `Superclass` is very expansive. So I would need a way to do this without changing code in `Hello`

Any suggestions on how this could be achieved?

Comment: Is this related to CANDU reactors?

Comment: haha good guess. No, it's related to Candu Labs: https://www.candu.ai/

Answer (score 3):

If `myMacro` worked outside `Hello` it should work inside `Superclass` as well

```
import scala.language.experimental.macros
import scala.reflect.macros.blackbox

def myMacro[T]: Seq[String] = macro impl[T]
def impl[T: c.WeakTypeTag](c: blackbox.Context): c.Tree = {
  import c.universe._
  val methodNames = weakTypeOf[T].decls
    .filter(symb => symb.isMethod && !symb.isConstructor)
    .map(_.name.toString).toList
  val methodNamesTree = methodNames.foldRight[Tree](q"Nil")((name, names) => q"$name :: $names")
  q"..$methodNamesTree"
}
```

Usage:

```
sealed trait Superclass {
  def aFakeMethod: String = ""

  val methods = myMacro[Hello]
}

val hi = new Hello
println(hi.methods) // List("one", "two", "three")
```

If for some reason you can't use the name of `Hello` you can try to make `Superclass` sealed and use `knownDirectSubclasses`

```
def myMacro1(): Seq[String] = macro impl1
def impl1(c: blackbox.Context)(): c.Tree = {
  import c.universe._
  val child = c.enclosingClass.symbol.asClass.knownDirectSubclasses.head
  q"myMacro[$child]"
}
```

Usage:

```
sealed trait Superclass {
  def aFakeMethod: String = ""

  val methods = myMacro1()
}

val hi = new Hello
println(hi.methods) // List("one", "two", "three")
```

Or you can replace deprecated `c.enclosingClass.symbol.asClass` with `c.internal.enclosingOwner.owner.asClass` (now `enclosingOwner` is `val methods`, `enclosingOwner.owner` is `trait Superclass`).

---

If you can't make `Superclass` sealed try to traverse all classes and look for those extending `Superclass`

```
def myMacro2(): Seq[Seq[String]] = macro impl2

def impl2(c: blackbox.Context)(): c.Tree = {
  import c.universe._

  def treeSymbol(tree: Tree): Symbol = c.typecheck(tree, mode = c.TYPEmode).symbol
  val enclosingClassSymbol = c.internal.enclosingOwner.owner
  def isEnclosingClass(tree: Tree): Boolean = treeSymbol(tree) == enclosingClassSymbol

  var methodss = Seq[Seq[String]]()

  val traverser = new Traverser {
    override def traverse(tree: Tree): Unit = {
      tree match {
        case q"$_ class $_[..$_] $_(...$_) extends { ..$_ } with ..$parents { $_ => ..$stats }"
          if parents.exists(isEnclosingClass(_)) =>

          val methods = stats.collect {
            case q"$_ def $tname[..$_](...$_): $_ = $_" => tname.toString
          }
          methodss :+= methods

        case _ => ()
      }
        
      super.traverse(tree)
    }
  }

  c.enclosingRun.units.foreach(unit => traverser.traverse(unit.body))

  def namesToTree[A: Liftable](names: Seq[A]): Tree =
    names.foldRight[Tree](q"Seq()")((name, names) => q"$name +: $names")

  namesToTree[Tree](methodss.map(namesToTree[String](_)))
}
```

Usage:

```
trait Superclass {
  def aFakeMethod: String = ""

  val methods = myMacro2()
}

class Hello1 extends Superclass {
  def four = ???
  def five = ???
}

class Hello extends Superclass {
  def one(a: Int, b: UserId): String = a.toString + b.id
  def two(c: Option[Int]): String = ""
  def three(d: Seq[Int], f: Set[Int]): String = ""
}
  
val hi = new Hello
println(hi.methods) // List(List("four", "five"), List("one", "two", "three"))
```

Comment: Thanks Dmytro. Unfortunately, neither solution would work in our codebase because the Superclass is inherited by over 100 classes around the codebase.

Unfortunately, we can't change it to a `sealed` trait, and naming all the 100 classes is impractical.